Foundry script not deploying: "max priority fee per gas higher than max fee per gas"
I'm trying to deploy a smart contract, that deploys fine in remix, but in foundry I keep getting:
server returned an error response: error code -32000: max priority fee per gas higher than max fee per gas

What settings do I use to get past this error?

You should update your --priority-gas-price. Usually something small like 1 works fine.
For example:
forge script script/yourScript.s.sol --priority-gas-price 1


Or 0. I believe it's the default on Remix
